# vc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jpa, orm

This is my xml code. The errors happen below the one-to-one and all the basic attributes contain errors. However, when I move the one-to-one to the bottom of the attributes list, the error goes away, which is odd.

```
  <one-to-one name="page" fetch="LAZY">
    <join-column name="PAGE_ID" referenced-column-name="PAGE_ID" updatable="false" insertable="false" />
  </one-to-one>
  <basic name="sublinkNm">
    <column name="SUBLINK_NM" />
  </basic>
  <basic name="descriptionTxt">
    <column name="DESCRIPTION_TXT" />
  </basic>
  <basic name="searchableFlg">
    <column name="SEARCHABLE_FLG" />
  </basic>
```

This is the error I get. The error is affecting a few of my xml files

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'basic'. One of '{"http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm":many-to-one, "http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm":one-to-many, "http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm":one-to-one, "http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm":variable-one-to-one, "http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm":many-to-many, "http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm":element-collection, "http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm":embedded, "http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm":transformation, "http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm":transient, "http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm":structure, "http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm":array}' is expected.   page.xml    /ccservices/src/com/dstoutput/cp/resource/jpa/mapping   line 68 XML Problem

Comment: Put the "basic" before "one-to-one"; see the XSD for ordering

Comment: Presumably the schema imposes an ordering and your instance isn't following it.